# Dibujo en OpenCV y Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Python, la cual usando la biblioteca de OpenCV y pasándole el alto y ancho, me cree una imagen RGB con las dimesiones pasadas y en la cual pueda dibujar y guradar posteriormente.

Estoy intentado algo así:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def imRGB(X, Y):
    img = np.zeros((X, Y, 3), np.uint8)
    cv2.line(img,(10, 0), (250, 128), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
    N = img
    N.save("imRGB.jpg")
```

Pero no consigo que funcione ya que me tira errores como:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Un salud y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `save` no existe para la clase `ndarray`, NumPy no tiene esta característica, aunque se use para trabajar con imágenes como contenedor aprovechando sus funciones matemáticas de alto nivel para tratar con matrices y vectores. En tu caso  simplemente puedes usar el método [`cv2.imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imwrite#cv2.imwrite) para crear tu imagen a partir del array de NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def imRGB(X, Y):
    img = np.zeros((X, Y, 3), np.uint8)
    cv2.line(img,(10, 0), (250, 128), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.imwrite('imRGB.jpg', img)
```